# How to style vertexes in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6, openlayers-5

I use [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-forked-v9ndqi?file=/main.js:1355-1706) code to draw polygons. How to set style for all vertexes including cutouts?

This is my attempt to style the vertex points:

```
function getStyleFunction() {
      const white = [255, 255, 255, 1];
      const blue = [0, 153, 255, 1];
      const width = 3;
      const styles = {
        Polygon: [
          new Style({
            fill: new Fill({
              color: [255, 255, 255, 0.6],
            }),
            stroke: new Stroke({
              color: blue,
              width: width,
            }),
          }),
        ],
        Point: [
          new Style({
            image: new CircleStyle({
              radius: width * 2,
              fill: new Fill({
                color: blue,
              }),
              stroke: new Stroke({
                color: white,
                width: width / 2,
              }),
            }),
          }),
        ],
      };
      return function (feature, resolution) {
        return styles[feature.getGeometry().getType()];
      };
    }
```

And styles for drawing object:

```
const draw = new Draw({
  source: source,
  type: 'Polygon',
  style: getStyleFunction(),
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73011556/10118270 you will need a geometry function to produce MultiPoint to style the vertices.  Instead of just the first ring  if you want the vertices of all rings replace `feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[0]` with `feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates().flat()` https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-forked-p41i2u?file=/main.js